# How to change the default behaviour so that CMD + Tab brings the app on top?

Tags: application-switcher

I have many apps.

CMD + Tab is the fastest way to switch (me using keyboard only)

**BUT**

It is rubbish because it does not bring the application on top.

After some search, apparently this is a feature not a bug: [Cmd+Tab switches to the correct space, but doesn't bring app up to front](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29705/cmdtab-switches-to-the-correct-space-but-doesnt-bring-app-up-to-front)

> Whether it was intended as a feature or not, it is clearly a usability issue, aka a bug

I just want to use CMD + Tab and bring the app on top by default (change the setting somewhere) rather than relying on a very tricky additional keypress.

---

Another related question: [Bring all windows of active application to top](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101577/bring-all-windows-of-active-application-to-top)

On my machine I don't have "Bring All To Front":

[image]

Comment: You have to add Bring All to Front manually, the same as any other menu command. [I've edited that into the linked QA]

Comment: BTW, I've always thought Cmd/Tab is one of the worst ways to switch apps. Spaces is far better - see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm using 2x 32 inch monitor and I have many apps open. Not using spaces. I just want to bring the app on top, not changing my entire setup :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer on [Cmd+Tab does not work on hidden or minimized windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396250/432296).

It's incredible that Apple has to add so many features and none of them meets such a simple feature of use.